# HTML5 canvas not rendering image retreieved through rest service

Tags: html, rest, canvas

I am trying to draw an image retrieved from rest service, on a HTML canvas. Although everything runs successfully and console logs are printed fine but nothing the image does not get drawn on the canvas.
Here is my rest service -

```
 @Controller
 public class HomePicture {

 @Autowired
 ServletContext context; 

@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
        value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getPicture() throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/images/marina.jpg");
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}

}
```

Following is my script inside my html where I am using this picture -

```
     function getData() {
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/showcase/Home",
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "text",
            success: successFn,
            error: errorFn,
            complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            console.log("The request is complete!");
             }
            });
          }

          function successFn(result) {
            console.log("Setting result ");

            var canVas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas")
            var ctx = canVas.getContext("2d");
            var img = new Image;
            img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
            }
            img.src = result;
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in the console? One possible culprit is the port change in the address you're calling in the Ajax

Comment: Ajax call is working fine. If I change MediaType to text value, it gets displayed properly. It's the Byte array read, which is creating problem